# R -Eye Tracking packages for SMI's BeGaze users

Tags: r, package, data-processing, eye-tracking

Currently, we are working on an eye-tracking study and we are not quite satisfied with the analysis option of SMI’s BeGaze. Hence, I would like to ask you know good way to extract data from BeGaze, which can be processed by a handy R-package, which is still working under R 3.6.1 – not like ETRAN.
It would be great to do add AOIs manually, do heat maps, analyze saccades, fixation times, and ratios between AOIs.

We came across eyetrackingR, but we are still struggling with extracting BeGaze's data in a processable way.

Any help, tutorial, hint, etc. is much appreciated.

David

Comment: This is just a comment as I'm not near the lab at the moment, but you should also have a couple of utilities installed - associated with the iView software rather than BeGaze - called something like _IDF Converter_ and _Event detector_. These open an IDF file and export either the raw data stream in the first case, or a processed series of parsed events (saccades and fixations) in the latter case. These are text rather than binary files, which can then be imported and processed in other software. BeGaze itself can also export events at least.

Comment: More details on "we are still struggling with extracting BeGaze's data in a processable way" would be useful, to know exactly where you are finding the issues.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill thanks for your input. The problem with BeGaze's event/trial statistics is that, for example, the AOI statistic don't show data per participant in the trial summary and the event statistics do not include AOIs.

By in a "processable way" I meant that we can extract the raw data in a way so that we can do AOIs, saccades, heatmaps, and scanpaths in R.

Thank you very much for your help.

David